# Pygame mouse click and rect intersection

Tags: python, pygame

I am designing a survival based game, and I am having trouble allowing the player to collect wood from trees.

The function below checks if my mouse is pressed, and if the player has collided with any tree rects, their wood count increases by one. I use the ticks to make sure that only one wood gets added every nine ticks.

```
def check(self):
    global tick
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: 
        for tree in resources:
            tree_rect=tree.rect                                
            if self.rect.colliderect(tree_rect) and tick>=9:
                self.inventory['wood']+=1
                tick=0
```

However, whenever I click, wood is sometimes added and sometimes not, regardless of whether my player class has collided with any trees.

I tried using `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`, but the result was the same. Any help is appreciated.

Full code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import sys
import math
import pygame.gfxdraw
import random

pygame.init()

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
forest=(34,139,34)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
green=(0,255,0)
light_green=(0,120,0)
dark_green=(0,90,0)
skin=(255,224,189)
yellow=(255,255,0)

wood_image=pygame.image.load('./assets/images/wood.png')
stone_image=pygame.image.load('./assets/images/stone.png')
player_image=pygame.image.load('./assets/images/player.png')

tick=0

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawTextcenter(text,font,screen,x,y,color):
    textobj=font.render(text,True,color)
    textrect=textobj.get_rect(center=(x,y))
    screen.blit(textobj,textrect)

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y,color):
    textobj=font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect=textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft=(x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

class Button(object):
    global screen_width,screen_height,screen
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,text_color,background_color,text):
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.text=text
        self.text_color=text_color
        self.background_color=background_color
        self.angle=0

    def check(self):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.background_color,(self.rect),0)
        drawTextcenter(self.text,font,screen,self.x+self.width/2,self.y+self.height/2,self.text_color)  
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.text_color,self.rect,3) 

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,length,color):
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,length,17.5)
        self.image=pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(self.rect),)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=100
        self.height=17.5
        self.color=color
        self.multiplier=length/100

    def draw(self,num): 
        rect=pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,num*self.multiplier,self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,self.rect,3)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,rect,0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.image=player_image
        self.original_image=self.image
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=(x,y))
        self.change_x=0
        self.change_y=0
        self.speed=7.5
        self.inventory={'wood':0}

    def changespeed(self,x,y):
        self.change_x+=x
        self.change_y+=y

    def update(self,rect):
        self.rotate(camera)
        self.rect.x+=self.change_x
        self.rect.y+=self.change_y
        rect = camera.apply(self)
        screen.blit(self.image,rect)

    def check(self):
        global tick
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: 
            for tree in resources:
                tree_rect=tree.rect                                
                if self.rect.colliderect(tree_rect) and tick>=9:
                    self.inventory['wood']+=1
                    tick=0

    def rotate(self,camera):
        mouse_x,mouse_y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_x-=camera.state.x
        mouse_y-=camera.state.y
        rel_x,rel_y= mouse_x - self.rect.centerx, mouse_y -self.rect.centery
        angle = -math.degrees(math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.original_image, angle,1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Tree,self).__init__()
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,100,100)
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y

    def update(self,rect):
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(screen,rect.x,rect.y,80,light_green)
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen,rect.x,rect.y,80,light_green)

class Rock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self,camera_func,width,height):
        self.camera_func=camera_func
        self.state=pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height)

    def apply(self,target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self,target):
        self.state=self.camera_func(self.state,target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t = target_rect.center
    _,_,w,h = camera
    l,t,_,_ = -l+screen_width/2, -t+screen_height/2, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           
    l = max(-(camera.width-screen_width), l)
    t = max(-(camera.height-screen_height), t)
    t = min(0, t)                           

    return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,40)

screen_width=1440
screen_height=800
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption('Survival')

total_level_width=screen_width*5
total_level_height=screen_height*5
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)

player=Player(random.randint(100,7900),random.randint(100,5900))
friendlies=pygame.sprite.Group()
friendlies.add(player)

player_health_bar=Bar(125,15,200,green)
player_health=100
player_food_bar=Bar(437.5,15,200,red)
player_food=100
player_thirst_bar=Bar(750,15,200,blue)
player_thirst=100
player_energy_bar=Bar(1100,15,200,yellow)
player_energy=100

resources=pygame.sprite.Group()

wood=False
inventory={}

for i in range(1000):
    tree=Tree(random.randint(100,7900),random.randint(100,5900))
    resources.add(tree)

done1=False
while not done1:
    screen.fill(black)
    font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 90)
    text_width,text_height=font.size('Survival')
    drawText('Survival', font, screen, (screen_width/2-text_width/2), (screen_height / 2-375),white)
    font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
    start_button=Button(screen_width/2-125,450,250,50,white,black,'Play')
    start_button.draw()
    back_button=Button(screen_width/2-125,725,250,50,white,black,'Back')
    pygame.display.flip()
    done2=False
    while not done2:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if start_button.check()==True: 
                    done3=False
                    pause_back=False
                    while not done3:             
                        tick+=1
                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                                terminate()
                            elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                                    player.changespeed(-(player.speed), 0)
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                                    player.changespeed(player.speed, 0)
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_w:
                                    player.changespeed(0, -(player.speed))
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                                    player.changespeed(0, player.speed)
                                elif event.key==pygame.K_p:
                                    font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 90)
                                    text_width,text_height=font.size('Paused')
                                    drawText('Paused', font, screen, (screen_width / 2-(text_width/2)), (screen_height / 2-375),white)
                                    resume_button=Button(screen_width/2-125,650,250,50,white,black,'Resume')
                                    resume_button.draw()
                                    back_button.draw()
                                    pygame.display.flip()
                                    back=False
                                    while not back:
                                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                                            if event.type==QUIT:
                                                terminate()
                                            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                                                if resume_button.check()==True:
                                                    back=True
                                                elif back_button.check()==True:
                                                    done3=True
                                                    done2=True
                                                    pause_back=True
                                                    back=True

                            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                                    player.changespeed(player.speed, 0)
                                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                                    player.changespeed(-(player.speed), 0)
                                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                                    player.changespeed(0, player.speed)
                                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                                    player.changespeed(0, -(player.speed))   

                        camera.update(player)

                        if player.rect.x<0:
                            player.rect.x=0
                        if player.rect.right>total_level_width:
                            player.rect.right=total_level_width
                        if player.rect.y<0:
                            player.rect.y=0
                        if player.rect.bottom>total_level_height:
                            player.rect.bottom=total_level_height

                        screen.fill(dark_green)

                        player.update(camera)

                        for resource in resources:
                            resource.update(camera.apply(resource))

                        player_health_bar.draw(player_health)
                        #player_thirst_bar.draw(player_thirst)
                        #player_endergy_bar.draw(player_energy)
                        font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
                        drawText('Health:',font,screen,20,10,green)
                        #drawText('Food:',font,screen,350,10,red)
                        #drawText('Thirst:',font,screen,650,10,blue)
                        #drawText('Energy:', font, screen, 975, 10, yellow)
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,forest,(50,675,100,100))
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,forest,(175,675,100,100))
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen,forest,(300,675,100,100))

                        player.check()

                        for item in player.inventory:
                            if item=='wood' and player.inventory['wood']>0:
                                wood=True

                        if wood:
                            screen.blit(wood_image,(62.5,687.5))
                            drawTextcenter(str(player.inventory['wood']),font,screen,100,735,black)

                        pygame.display.flip()

                        clock.tick(100)

                        if pause_back==True:
                                break
                    if pause_back==True:
                        break
                    screen.fill(black)
                    font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 90)
                    text_width,text_height=font.size("Game Over")
                    drawText('Game Over', font, screen, (screen_width/2-text_width/2), (screen_height / 2-200),white)
                    font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
                    retry_button=Button(screen_width/2-125,650,250,50,white,black,'Retry')
                    retry_button.draw()
                    back_button.draw()
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    back=False 
                    while not back:
                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                                if event.type==QUIT:
                                    terminate()
                                elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                                    if retry_button.check()==True:
                                        back=True
                                    if back_button.check()==True:
                                        back=True
                                        done2=True
                                        done3=True        
                elif back_button.check()==True: 
                    done2=True
                    done1=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the `rect` in the `Tree.update` method and you'll see what's wrong.

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (120, 50, 0), rect)
```

You're using the `x` and `y` (the `topleft`) coords of the `rect` as the center point of the circle, so the rect will be in the lower right quadrant of the tree.

```
    =  =    
 =        =
=      ____=___
=     |    =   |
 =    |   =    |
    = |=       |
      |________|
```

Use the `centerx` and `centery` coordinates instead:

```
pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(screen, rect.centerx, rect.centery, 80, light_green)
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, rect.centerx, rect.centery, 80, light_green)
```